# problem with update strong typed dataset turn to database in C# .net framework 3.5

Tags: dataset, typed

I want to remove some special characters in a table of database. I've used strong typed table to do it. When i got all data into dataset from database and modified it then i called method update() of data adapter to turn dataset to database but it doesn't work.

Below is my code

```
DsTel tel = new DsTel();

            DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter adapter = new DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter();
            adapter.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteSqlServer"].ToString());
            adapter.Fill(tel.telephone_bk);

            foreach (DsTel.telephone_bkRow row in tel.telephone_bk.Rows)
            {

                row.telephoneNo = RemoveWhiteSpace(row.telephoneNo.ToString());
                row.AcceptChanges();
            }
            tel.AcceptChanges();
            adapter.Update(tel.telephone_bk);
```

Please give me some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more details about the failure?  Are you getting an error, or is the data being written incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for this problem by using the TableAdapterManager.

Below is my code:

DsTel tel = new DsTel();

```
            DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter adapter = new DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter();
            adapter.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteSqlServer"].ToString());

            adapter.Fill(tel.telephone_bk);

            foreach (DsTel.telephone_bkRow row in tel.telephone_bk.Rows)
            {
                                    if (!row.IstelephoneNoNull())
                {

                    row.telephoneNo = RemoveWhiteSpace(row.telephoneNo.ToString());
                }


            }

            DsTelTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager mrg = new DsTelTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
            mrg.telephone_bkTableAdapter = adapter;
            mrg.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate = true;
            mrg.UpdateAll((DsTel)tel.GetChanges());
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called `AcceptChanges` before the update.  This means the dataset has no changes any more so there is nothing to send to the database.
Remove all of the calls to `AcceptChanges` and add one AFTER the update. ie:

```
DsTel tel = new DsTel();

DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter adapter = new DsTelTableAdapters.telephone_bkTableAdapter();
adapter.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteSqlServer"].ToString());
adapter.Fill(tel.telephone_bk);
foreach (DsTel.telephone_bkRow row in tel.telephone_bk.Rows)
{
    row.telephoneNo = RemoveWhiteSpace(row.telephoneNo.ToString());
}
adapter.Update(tel.telephone_bk);
tel.telephone_bk.AcceptChanges();
```